Insall plugin redminex_ckeditor in redmine docker throws bundler error
I'm migrating my old redmine 2.6 to a newer version (5.x). Migration by itself worked great. I can find my issues and config. Everything seems ok.
I need to import plugins now. The first one is already causing me some troubles.
Plugin: CK-Editor FREE by RedmineX
https://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine-x-ck-editor-free
Version of Docker Redmine tested :
redmine:latest
redmine:5.0.9
redmine:5.0.5

Error messages :
Installing mimemagic 0.3.10 with native extensions
Bundler::DirectoryRemovalError: Could not delete previous installation of
`/usr/local/bundle/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10`.
The underlying error was ArgumentError: parent directory is world writable,
Bundler::FileUtils#remove_entry_secure does not work; abort:
"/usr/local/bundle/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10" (parent directory mode 40777), with
backtrace:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/fileutils/lib/fileutils.rb:1387:in
`remove_entry_secure'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler.rb:332:in `rm_rf'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:111:in
`strict_rm_rf'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:19:in `install'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:202:in `install'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:156:in

`do_install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:147:in
`block in worker_pool'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in
create_threads'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:115:in `rescue in
strict_rm_rf'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:110:in
`strict_rm_rf'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:19:in `install'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:202:in `install'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:156:in

`do_install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:147:in
`block in worker_pool'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in
create_threads'
An error occurred while installing mimemagic (0.3.10), and Bundler cannot

.
In Gemfile:
  paperclip was resolved to 6.1.0, which depends on
    mimemagic

Does anyone managed to install it ? What shall I do ?

Finally found the way to do it. It requires to use entrypoint to change authorizations on some folder and install mime-info
redmine:
    image: redmine:latest
    container_name: redmine
    restart: always
    environment:
      REDMINE_DB_ADAPTER: "sqlserver"
      REDMINE_DB_SQLSERVER: "xx.xx.xx.xx"
      REDMINE_DB_PORT: "1433"
      REDMINE_DB_USERNAME: "username"
      REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD: "password"
      VIRTUAL_HOST: "sub.domain.com"
      REDMINE_PLUGINS_MIGRATE: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - REDMINE_DATA:/usr/src/redmine/files
      - REDMINE_PLUGINS:/usr/src/redmine/plugins
    networks:
      - common_network
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "chmod -R o-w \"$$GEM_HOME/gems\" && chmod -R o-w \"$$GEM_HOME/extensions\" && apt-get update && apt-get install -y shared-mime-info && /docker-entrypoint.sh rails server -b 0.0.0.0"]

